# Questions for sentences in Phaedrus's «Aesopus Latinus»

Tags: grammar-identification, phaedrus

I have some problems in understanding these sentences in *Phaedrus, III.7* (the wolf and the dog):

- > Canis simpliciter: "Eadem est condiciō tibi, **praestāre** dominō sī pār officium potes."

Why is an infinitive **praestāre** here? Is it for **potes**? If so what is the verb for the **sī** clause? or is the infinitive hortative/imperative?

- > "Quod?" inquit ille (:=lupus). [Canis:] "Cūstōs **ut** sīs līminis..."

Is the **ut** optative?

- > crepusculō solūtus quā vīsum est vagor.

= "At dusk when I am allowed, I wander, being solved." ?

- > [Lupus:] "Fruere quae laudās, canis! Rēgnāre nōlō, līber ut nōn sim mihī."

Why does it say "I don't want to rule, so that I may not be free"? What's the logic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- > Canis simpliciter: "Eadem est condiciō tibi, praestāre dominō sī pār officium potes."

  = *sī potes* [quid?] pār officium [cui?] dominō [quid facere?] praestāre
- > "Quod?" inquit ille (:=lupus). [Canis:] "Cūstōs ut sīs līminis..."

  = *quod **officium?** ut custōs sīs līminis.* It's a description of the duty, 'to guard the entrance'.

  > crepusculō solūtus quā vīsum est vagor.

  *solūtus = **catēnīs** solūtus, expedītus, līber; quā vīsum est = quālibet, quācumque volō*
- > Rēgnāre nōlō, līber ut nōn sim mihī."

  = nōlō **ita** rēgnāre **ut** līber mihimet nōn sim. quī līber nōn est sibi, nōn rēgnat sed servit

Comment: Do you think *mihi* in the last verse, can be interpreted as: "as for me"; rather than "free to myself". its like: "you dog, go enjoy those things you so praise, as for me, I rather be free than to be happy slave"

Comment: @d_e No, it's a respect adjunct to *līber* - 'free with respect to myself', like for example in *rēx cēterīs* 'a king to others'. This is clear because of its sentence-final position which cannot express contrastive topic; cf. [my answer here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/17898/2389). The wolf doesn't want to be a king with respect to others only to be a slave with respect to himself.